# pimcore object class: getting all data

Tags: php, pimcore

i'm new to pimcore and created an object class - here's the code snippet which will get the field "title" when saving the record:

```
class MagentoBaseProduct extends Concrete {

    public function getTitle () {
        $preValue = $this->preGetValue("title"); 
        if($preValue !== null && !\Pimcore::inAdmin()) { 
            return $preValue;
        }
        $data = $this->title;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

i was wondering if there's away getting the whole object so that i will get all fields in one array (instead of getting each field separately)?

thanks

Comment: out of curiosity, what would be a usecase for this?

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick much easier:

```
$data = []; 
$myObj = \Object\MagentoBaseProduct::getById(123);
foreach($myObj->getClass()->getFieldDefinitions() as $fieldDefionition) {
    $data[$fieldDefinition->getName()] = $myObj->getValueForFieldName($fieldDefinition->getName()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's introspection capabilities to get a list of getters in the object then access each getter in turn to get the values and build the array from this.  Remember values may not be simple strings - they could be other objects, field collections or anything else Pimcore allows.

```
$myObj = \Object\MagentoBaseProduct::getById(123);
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($myObj);
$methods = $reflection->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $methodName = $method->getName();
    if (substr($methodName, 0, 3) == 'get') {
        // do stuff to add to array here
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php